# React-Native Why does this come up with "is not iterable"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

New to React / State / Arrays.

Why does this come up with "is not iterable"

```
  const myVar = {
    '2022-11-22': { selected: true, textColor: 'blue', activeOpacity: 0}
  };
 
  const [myMarkedDates, setMarkedDates] = useState(myVar);
 
  const newVar = {
    '2022-12-17': {selected: true, textColor: 'red', activeOpacity: 0}
  };
  
  const newVars = [newVar, ...myMarkedDates];
 
  setMarkedDates(newVars);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing an array with an object here.
The spread notation using `...myMarkedDates` returns the properties of the object:

```
'2022-11-22': { selected: true, textColor: 'blue', activeOpacity: 0}
```

This can be a property of another object, but NOT an element inside the array.

This would be a valid syntax for you:

```
const newVars = [newVar, {...myVar}];
```

Here `newVars` will be an array containing the objects `newVar` and `myVar`:

```
[
  {
    '2022-12-17': { selected: true, textColor: 'red', activeOpacity: 0 }
  },
  {
    '2022-11-22': { selected: true, textColor: 'blue', activeOpacity: 0 }
  }
]
```

Depending on what you are trying to achieve this might be preferred:

```
const newVars = {...newVar, ...myVar};
```

In the code above `newVars` will be an object with the properties of `newVar` and `myVar` combined:

```
{
  '2022-12-17': { selected: true, textColor: 'red', activeOpacity: 0 },
  '2022-11-22': { selected: true, textColor: 'blue', activeOpacity: 0 }
}
```

Comment: So I thought this would work, however I can't use a State variable then to update the state?

When I try

```
 const newVars = {...newVar, ...myVar};

  setMarkedDates(newVars);
```
I get Error Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: This is an issue related to the conditions in which you are calling the setState function. It wasn’t part of your question and it is probably related to bits of your code that are not shown.

Comment: That is my entire code segment for this proof of concept.  Just go to codesandbox . io and put that in just aff the App() and it does not work.

Comment: That’s really strange because nothing is being rendered in this segment.